# splitting a string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

What would be the best way to split a string array in certain index to make a string matrix removing the element you split.  For example, for the string array `["Good","Bad","Sad"]` if i split it at 1 it would give me a string matrix that looked like this `[["Good"],["Sad"]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well ivanovic's answer explains how to simply remove one element from a string sequence with java Collection (List). And it is indeed the straightforward way to achieve that goal (removing element).

However, my understanding of OP's question is, he gets an string array as parameter, and wants a 2-D String array to get returned. the "split-index" element should not be included in the result String[][].

Base on my understanding, I therefore add another answer:

```
final String[] input = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight" };
        final int len = input.length;
        final int pos = 3;
        final String[][] result = new String[2][Math.max(pos, len - pos - 1)];
        result[0] = Arrays.copyOf(input, pos);
        result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, pos + 1, len);
```

well this is even not a java-method, but it explains how to get the result. in the example above, the result would be a 2-d array, `[[one, two, three], [five, six, seven, eight]]`

EDIT:

wrap it in a method is easy:

```
public static String[][] splitStringArray(String[] input, int pos) {
        final int len = input.length;
        final String[][] result = new String[2][Math.max(pos, len - pos - 1)];
        result[0] = Arrays.copyOf(input, pos);
        result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, pos + 1, len);
        return result;
    }
```

Note that error handling part is not there, e.g. pos outofbound handling,  NPE checking (input) etc. you could do it by yourself I believe.

Comment: Could you wrap this in a method maybe im not exactly sure what each variable is doing

Comment: @popgalop there was a hardcoded 3 in the code. it has been fixed. copy the method from my answer, try again.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ArrayList` instead of array. Removing a random element from an arraylist is quite easy since it is dynamic.

```
ArrayList>String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
...
list.remove(1);
```

Comment: But `LinkedList` will be more efficient as we know.

Comment: And to seperate into different lists, there's a `subList` method for that. `list.subList(0, 3)` for example.

Comment: Did I misunderstand OP's question? Collecion api does make removing element easier than array. However (s)he wants a multi-dimension array as result. in fact, it would be 2D String array. And particularly with "multidimensional-array" tag. Did you suggest him/her first converting the array to list then converting the result list into array(2-d) again?

Comment: well what i need it for is for a tetris game and in order to use the collection framework i would have to rewrite a lot of code so i would really prefer to stick to arrays however if their is an easy way to convert an array to an arraylist and split it that way, that would be fine